# How can we choose most recent Paypal Payment page?

Tags: user-interface, paypal

I'm setting up a Paypal Account for a client. Its a little organization, so they choose the free Business Account to collect payments. For the moment, they can't afford the Pro version.

I want to know : how use the most recent interface for payments ?

**This is the interface I want :** [image]

**Instead of the ugly "old" one :** 
[image]

I search in the Paypal website but I have no clues. I want to use the newer version because the button for non-Paypal user is really much more user-friendly and don't force people to create Paypal Account to pay.

Edit : I also need to use the IPN system to send data bak to my website.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while searching for this as well. In the code for your button replace the form as follows:

Before:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
```

After:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/donate/?token=" method="post" target="_top">
```

Try also adding this snippet as one of the inputs for the form if the prior doesn't work. I read this part on another post in SO, but I forgot the link:

```
<input type="hidden" name="force_sa" value="false">
```

For your curiosity and future debugging:

I found this solution because the old interface would appear in chrome during normal mode, but the new interface would appear in chrome incognito/private mode. I tried using chrome dev tools but I merely noticed the URL differences and replaced it accordingly in my code.

Hope that helps!